# Filling every other row with the value of the following row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to fill every other row in an excel worksheet with the value that is following that row.

See example.

[image: imager example]

Is there a way to accomplish this?
I am sorry if this is an extremely easy task, but I just can't get my head around how this may work, since just plain copying the data, filtering for blank rows and pasting it into the filtered table just doesn't work as I want it to.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: It might be worth adding that I cannot at all change rows or columns in the excel sheet since it is connected to a database which configuration does not allow this.

Comment: You could create a new sheet in which A2 has the value `=A3`, and fill down/right to cover desired range, then paste the values from your old sheet over the top of it. Why do you need to duplicate these values though?

Comment: Thanks for answering but what do you mean with copying "the values over the top of it"?
I edited bulk prices of items. Explaining the whole task would lead too far away from the topic in this post, but just know that we have a poorly administered database which lead to this kind of weird structure. I work at the company for 1 month and am now stuck with the task to somewhwat "clean out" the database.

Comment: Tip: Make use of 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` when you loop through a range when you decide you go VBA route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a new helper column with the formula `=ISEVEN(ROW())`.
2. Filter this column on `TRUE`.
3. Select the range from A2 to the bottom-right of the cells that you want to populate, and input `=A3` [Ctrl-Enter].
4. Clear the filter and delete the helper column.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped. Have a nice day.